# Сделать текст по центру другого текста

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно чтобы были звезды  по центру, а то выглядит как-то убого, как это отформатировать?
Мне именно нужна строка потому-то  ее передаю серверу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 private void SendTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            if (sendTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                string msg = sendTextBox.Text;
                sendTextBox.Clear();
                bool isbanedword = ForbiddenWords.Any(w => w == msg);
                
                if(!isbanedword)
                {
                    Log(string.Format("{0} (You): {1}", obj.username, msg));
                    if (connected)
                    {
                        Send(msg);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    string stars = new string('*', msg.Length);
                    msg = $"This word can not write:{stars}";
                    Log(string.Format("{0} (You): {1}", obj.username, msg));
                    if (connected)
                    {
                        Send(msg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 100% рабочий вариант - это отредактировать сам шрифт и затем использовать этот кастомный вариант шрифта. Но есть один момент, ежели у вас коммерческий проект - то при этом придется соблюдать copyright или использовать GNU-шные шрифты.

Comment: Поменяй символ на тот что по центру, [тут на любой вкус звёздочки](https://ru.piliapp.com/symbol/asterisk/)

Comment: Шрифт поставьте Consolas

Comment: @KuzCode cпасибо.

Comment: @Vladimir на здоровье)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое решеные: [тут](https://ru.piliapp.com/symbol/asterisk/) или поставить шрифты Consolas.

```
string stars = new string('✱', msg.Length);
msg = $"This word can not write:{stars}";
Log(string.Format("{0} (You): {1}", obj.username, msg));
```

Comment: ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀